# TableView RowSelected with SearchResultsTableView: Keeping Track of Cell Index for CheckMark

Tags: c#, json, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `tableview` that I've created from a JSON file that keeps track of the checked/unchecked status of the cell. The only problem is that when I implemented a `SearchResults` view, my results are skewed because I check the cell at the index path, and I update the corresponding JSON entry (`SubscribeStatus`).

```cs
 var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
```

Wondering if there is another way modify, or figure out another approach that takes into account the correct index for the search results displayed.  Here is some sample code below:

```cs
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView,NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
        var value = this.tableviewController.TableView==search.SearchResultsTableView ? filteredDataList[indexPath.Row] : dataList[indexPath.Row];

        if (value.Selected)
        {
            value.Selected = false;

            var uncheckedImage = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromBundle("unchecked"));

            cell.AccessoryView = uncheckedImage;
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);  
            var localPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "marketnibble_sample_customers.json");
            string json = File.ReadAllText (localPath);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (json);
            jsonObj ["Business"] [indexPath.Row] ["SubscribeStatus"] = false;
            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (jsonObj);
            File.WriteAllText (localPath, output);

        }
        else
        {
            value.Selected = true;

            var checkedImage = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromBundle("checked"));
            cell.AccessoryView = checkedImage;

            string documentsPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
            var localPath1 = Path.Combine(documentsPath1, "marketnibble_sample_customers.json");
            string json = File.ReadAllText(localPath1);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (json);
            jsonObj["Business"][indexPath.Row]["SubscribeStatus"] = true;
            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
            File.WriteAllText (localPath1, output);

        }
        cell.Selected = false;
        tableviewController.TableView.ReloadData ();
    }
```

I've heard of a way to do this with `cell.Tag()`, but don't have a clue where to begin. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way other than indexPath to map a cell to it's underlying data.  You can use the Tag property to do this - Tag is just a string that you can use for whatever you like.  The easiest approach would be to store the ID or Key property of your JSON element in the Tag, and then whenever a cell is selected, you can use the Tag proprerty to find the underlying data in the JSON and update it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are storing you data in file. You might do this for persist storage. But this is not good way i suggested instead if you will use coredata than it will more helpful.

You have to make one entity that will store your selection state also.

And one more thing there is no need to reload table on select row just update that select row only.

Comment: Thanks will look into it, I think the Tag property is the way to go.